# Need to know qsub completed job ids

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, qsub

I have a script that is posting bunch of qsub jobs. I can use following command to check job status.

```
qstat -u <user name>
```

I want to find out completed job ids. What command I need to use for that?

Comment: From the qsub tag wiki: Questions with the "qsub" tag should clearly indicate which resource manager or scheduler is being used.

Comment: I have edited the question for clarity.